# MATLAB Hamming window

Tags: matlab, filters, window-functions

I have been trying to achieve a Hamming window length of 23 using the equation.

I tried several coding, one of the is the one below:

```
M=23
w = .54 + .46*cos(pi*(-M:M-1)'/M)
plot(w)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length of the window should be $23$, $M$ must equal $(23-1)/2=11$:

```
M = 11;
m = -M:M;
w = .54 + .46*cos(pi*m/M);
plot(m,w)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

- Evaluate the cosine only at 23 points, not at 46 like you're doing in your code above.
- Generate a time vector to go with your window signal. This means you'll also need to specify your sampling frequency.

You can do it like this:

```
M = 23;    % samples in the window
Ts = 1;    % sampling interval
w = 0.54+0.46*cos((2*pi/(M-1))*(-(M-1)/2:(M-1)/2));  % window
t = Ts*(-(M-1)/2:(M-1)/2);  % time vector
plot(t,w);
```

Note that I've used a slightly different definition of the window formula. This code produces the same window as Matlab's `hamming` command.

Answer (score -1):

There is a default function in MatLab which can generate this for you, called [hamming](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/hamming.html). In case you do not have access to this function, because you do not have the signal processing toolbox, you could try:

```
M = 23;
w = 0.54 - 0.46 * cos(2 * pi * linspace(0, 1, M));
```